# i got error while running the code on emulator in android studio bumblebee 2021.1.1 patch 3

Tags: java, android, build.gradle

This is my error:

```
Build file 'C:\Users\ayush\AndroidStudioProjects\MyworkSpaceApp\app\build.gradle' line: 2

An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.AppPlugin$ApplicationAndroidComponentsExtensionImplCompat.
      > Could not generate a decorated class for type AppPlugin.ApplicationAndroidComponentsExtensionImplCompat.
         > Cannot have abstract method AndroidComponentsExtension.registerSourceType().
```

Comment: Did you solved it eventually?

Comment: Got the same problem... Did you found out why?